# Tabs compitability issues with IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been following [this guide](http://www.xul.fr/javascript/tabs.php) in order to create tabs on my web application. 
I am using the exact same code and css from this example so you can use it as a reference.

As it says in the last pargraph there seem to be a compitability issue with IE.
While everything works in firefox in IE the layout looks really bad.

If I add the decleration mentioned there: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">` or `<!DOCTYPE html>` the tabs render correctly in both IE and Firefox however the container seem to be cutting the content of the pages in the middle.

I tried playing with the container element in the css but nothing seems to help.

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doctype is incorrect and puts you into quirks mode. Use this one: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Joly - Then there is something else in your markup affecting this, assuming the original markup really does work as he claims, but, without a link to yours, it's only wild guessing.

Comment: Mine is exactly the same, perhaps he tested it with different/older browser versions. I'm using FF8 and IE8. You are welcome to try this example and see :)

Comment: Well Rob, you were right. I forgot I changed the 'container' height attribute in the css to 100% instead of the height:350px; If I extend it to say 550px it works. A bit confused why the % doesn't work in this case tho....

Comment: @Joly - If you set the height to 100%, it's 100% of the parent container. What is the parent set to?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use javascript/jquery to do this same thing. I have included some sample of work i have been doing today using exactly this.

In your nav bar, divs for your tabs. e.g.

```
<div id="home">Home</div>
<div id="about">About</div>
```

In a content div below your menu bar.

```
<div id="content-holder">
    <div id="content1"></div>
    <div id="content2"></div>
</div>
```

The css for these 2 tab divs.

```
#home
{
    padding:4px 10px 4px 15px;
    cursor:pointer;         
}
#about

    padding:4px 10px 4px 15px;
    cursor:pointer;                         
}
```

and the javascript/jquery to control the transition.

```
var homeUrl = "link to content 1"
var aboutUrl = "link to content 2"
$("#home").click(function() {
$("#content-holder").load(homeUrl);         
});
$("#about").click(function() {
$("#content-holder").load(aboutUrl);        
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. Correct me if I'm wrong but using this method are we not preloading both content1 and content2 to the page? My pages are rather heavy and I'd like to aviod from doing it

Comment: It is preloading yes, although it is possible to load via ajax the new content. Ill update my answer to show this

Comment: Why the downvote dammit, cant you leave a comment to improve the answer instead? (n).

Comment: Apologies it was supposed to be a vote up actually!. I left it back on zero because when I try to vote up it puts it on -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iframes, the iframe needs to be big enough to hold all the content, or have a scroll bar. Iframe heights are set inline, not in css.